# How to Sort "Change View" List Drop-down

Tags: list, list-view

On a *list* item, on the *Browse* tab, you have the drop-down to select a view. My issue is, this list is ordered by the view's creation time. I would like it to be alphabetically. If you looks at changing the view from the ribbon, it is alphabetical.

An example:
For a new Calendar, the drop down is as follows:
Calendar
All Events
Current Events

it should be:
All Events
Calendar
Current Events

Is it possible, and how would I change the drop-down list of views to sort alphabetically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below link holds all the information you need to change this...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155803/How-to-sort-View-List-DropDown-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx

Unfortunately there does not currently seem to be a way to do this without powershell or editing the SQL DB directly.

Note: you should read the entire post as it goes over two methods, one with sql and another with a premade script. Go with whatever you feel most comfortable with!