# How to display all the 5 list views in specific order?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, list-view

I have a basic Custom List in **SharePoint Online (Office 365)** with 5 different views which their URLs are as follows:

View1 : https://Tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/SiteName/Lists/ListName/View1.aspx

View2 : https://Tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/SiteName/Lists/ListName/View2.aspx

View3 : https://Tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/SiteName/Lists/ListName/View3.aspx

View4 : https://Tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/SiteName/Lists/ListName/View4.aspx

View5 : https://Tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/SiteName/Lists/ListName/View5.aspx

I no longer have the "All Items" default view, Because I renamed it to "View1" and made it as my default.

Also, By design, SharePoint displays only Three views along with ellipsis (...).

**I really want to display all the Five views in a specific order** i.e.

View1  View5  View4  View3  View2

I tried adding Script Editor web part onto the default view page (https://Tenant.sharepoint.com/teams/SiteName/Lists/ListName/View1.aspx) with the suggested scripts that I found on:

[How to display more than 3 views in document library?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/112543/how-to-display-more-than-3-views-in-document-library)

[How do I change the displayed view order for a list in SharePoint 2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167831/how-do-i-change-the-displayed-view-order-for-a-list-in-sharepoint-2013)

https://afrait.com/blog/display-more-than-3-views-en/

Nothing seems to be working. Am I adding the script in the wrong location? Or, Is it because this SharePoint Online O365 ?

Please, Help me out !

Comment: Please note, that look and feel for lists are changing right now for SharePoint Online, and in future you will have to use old look to persist your customization. Otherwise you will lose your customization with modern lists UI.

Answer (score 1):

All those blogs do work in SPOnline

Simplest:

- Create a file `viewselector.js` in your ~sitecollection/Style Library

  ```
  console.info("My viewselector.js");
  ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function overrideSurfacePivotCount() {
      ClientPivotControl.prototype.SurfacedPivotCount = 99;
  }, 'clienttemplates.js');
  ```
- On the **first** ListView WebPart in you ASPX page,
  set a (WebPart Properties/Misc section) JSLink pointing to:
  `~sitecollection/Style Library/viewselector.js`

If you do not see that `console.info` output in the F12 Dev Tools window then the JSLink is wrong

Refer to the blogs you listed for more advanced coding