# Is there a way to reorder Views?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, list-view

I created a series of views for a Document Library (SharePoint Online), but I created them in the most convenient order. Is there a way to reorder the list to be alphabetical, rather than the order that I created them in?

**Update: Apparently if you wait ~ 24 Hours the View will update to be in Alphabetical order**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no OOTB way to do this. As you use the Online version, I think that you have three options, which are:

1. Try [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167831/how-do-i-change-the-displayed-view-order-for-a-list-in-sharepoint-2013) code.
2. If first option doesn't work, if I were you, I would inspect each hyperlink view in your list with Web Developers Tools of your browser. Once you get the HREF attribute and text of each hyperlink, create an Array with the desired order, and apply it to the each hyperlink view to see the desired order. Once I had the code, it would run on document.ready.
3. Create a custom lateral (or wherever) menu in the list page where you display the views, as buttons, for example, and hiding the native menu of views. More explained [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-reorder-the-SharePoint-list-views).

Of course, all the code wrapped up in a Content Editor Web Part or in the JSLink of the list web part.

Comment: If i'm working with modern lists, is it still possible to use this code through SPFx? Or will I need to recreate each of the views in the appropriate order?

Comment: What code do you mean? The one in the first option or, second or third you would have to code?

Comment: I was referring to the 1st option, but have since found a thread where SPFx needs to be used for modern pages/lists?