# Sort Order of the Views on a List Page

Tags: list, list-view, view

Is there a way change the order of the views listed on a list page (OOB or dynamically using JavaScript/JQuery)?  For instance, we want to show all of the views yet show/sort them in a specific order (ie., take the FY20 and put it at the end).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am basically getting the content from another question here in this site - [link here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167831/how-do-i-change-the-displayed-view-order-for-a-list-in-sharepoint-2013). Thanks ***Shashank Reddy K***

> Below is the javascript for JSLink(display template) file which does
>   the custom sorting.

You just need to change the order in the viewNames array with the order you want to display in your list.

```
(function () {     
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
      'Templates': {
        'Header': renderHeaderTemplateForDocuments
 }
}); 

// enter all views here in the desired display order
var viewNames = ['All items', 'Test', 'Dept View', 'HomePage', 'Modify this View', 'Create View'];

function renderHeaderTemplateForDocuments(renderCtx, fRenderHeaderColumnNames){
    var viewData = eval(renderCtx.ListSchema.ViewSelectorPivotMenuOptions);
    // update with an integer to specify the number of displayed views
    ClientPivotControl.prototype.SurfacedPivotCount = viewData.length;   //display ALL available menu options
    viewData.sort(compareMenuOptions);  //sort menu options in order specified in the array
    renderCtx.ListSchema.ViewSelectorPivotMenuOptions = JSON.stringify(viewData);
    return RenderHeaderTemplate(renderCtx, fRenderHeaderColumnNames); //render Header template
}

function compareMenuOptions(a,b) {
    if(a.DisplayText != undefined && b.DisplayText != undefined){
           var x = viewNames.indexOf(a.DisplayText);
           var y = viewNames.indexOf(b.DisplayText)
          if (x > y)
            return 1;
          if (x < y)
            return -1;
    }
  return 0;
}
})();
```

Another idea would be to have the views starting with numbers like 01.My View, 02.Another View, etc. - from ***Jammin4CO***

Comment: It worked however, it looks like I may have to do it for every view.