# Sort Sharepoint Online List views alphabetically

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have multiple Sharepoint Online lists each with more than 100+ views created.
The problem is that these views are listed in the order of creation and not alphabetically .
To navigate to a particular view it is getting very cumbersome to scroll through the long list.

I would like to know if it is possible to sort them out easily without renaming.

Answer (score 1):

I think the default view is always listed first followed by other views listed in **alphabetical ASC order**, not the creation order!

**To control the order of the list of views,**

- You have to rename the views in Alpabitic ASC order and I think it is a boring workaround especially if you have multiple views!

**Other workarounds,** if you are using classic experience is to use `JS link` as mentioned at

- [How do I change the displayed view order for a list in SharePoint 2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167831/how-do-i-change-the-displayed-view-order-for-a-list-in-sharepoint-2013)
- [Re-order SP2013 views](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162398/re-order-sp2013-views/162934)

**In case,** you are using modern experience, **you will not be able to use JS Link**, instead, try to migrate it to SharePoint Framework Extensions as mentioned at [Migrating from JSLink to SharePoint Framework extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/migrate-from-jslink-to-spfx-extensions?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002973)

Comment: The views after default view are not listed alphabetically on our Sharepoint Online Modern List and Library .

My requirement is to list them alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

In SharePoint Online, there's no way to change the order of the view. The only way is to change the view name.